# Using ros::service::call

Tags: ros, roscpp, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
could someone give me any exemples about ros::service::call?
i found osme information from the [API](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1service.html), but i need a concrete exemple.

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12661/using-ros::service::call/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [roscpp Overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Services) has an example of using `ros::service::call`.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3